# Insert/Update no funciona de manera correcta

Tags: php, java, mysql, android

**Buenas, estoy tratando de hacer lo siguiente utilizando `PHP/Android-Java/MySQL`: Quiero saber si al día de hoy, no existen datos cargados con una zona (fk) específica. De ser así, se debe hacer un `Insert` donde el valor ingresado se registra en dos campos de la tabla. Tabla:

```
idPrueba
precioMinimo
precioMaximo
fechaCarga
fkZona
```

Si hoy no hay datos cargado con la **fkZona = 1** (por ejemplo), debe hacer el `insert` ya mencionado. Supongamos que el valor ingresado es **500**, el resultado debe ser:

```
idPrueba = 100
precioMinimo = 500
precioMaximo = 500
fechaCarga = 2020-12-10
fkZona = 1
```

En caso de que existan datos al día de hoy con ese **fkZona = 1**, se debe hacer un Update según el valor ingresado. Suponiendo que tenemos los datos anteriores, ingresamos el valor **400** este valor, debe validarse contra los campos precioMinimo ó precioMaximo:

```
if(valor < precioMinimo)
```

Se hace el `update` al precio mínimo, con el valor actual:

```
idPrueba = 100
precioMinimo = 400
precioMaximo = 500
fechaCarga = 2020-12-10
fkZona = 1
```

En caso de que el valor sea 501:

```
if(valor > precioMaximo)
```

El `Update` se hace en el precioMaximo quedando:

```
idPrueba = 100
precioMinimo = 500
precioMaximo = 501
fechaCarga = 2020-12-10
fkZona = 1
```

En mi archivo `PHP` hice lo siguiente:

```
    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);
    // Check connection
    if (!$conn) {
          die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    
    $valor = $_POST[valor];
    $fkZona = $_POST[fkZona];
    $fechaCargaPrecio = $_POST[fechaCargaPrecio];
    $fkUsuario = $_POST[fkUsuario];
    
    $sqlNull = "SELECT * FROM cargaPrecioPapas WHERE fkZona = '$fkZona' AND fechaCargaPrecio IS NULL";
    
    $sqlMax = "SELECT precioMaximo FROM cargaPrecioPapas WHERE fkZona = '$fkZona' AND fechaCargaPrecio = CURDATE()";
    $sqlMin = "SELECT precioMinimo FROM cargaPrecioPapas WHERE fkZona = '$fkZona' AND fechaCargaPrecio = CURDATE()";
    
    //iinsert doble
    $sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO cargaPrecioPapas (precioMinimo, precioMaximo, fkZona, fechaCargaPrecio, fkUsuario) 
                 VALUES ('$valor', '$valor', '$fkZona', '$fechaCargaPrecio', '$fkUsuario');";
    
    //Update precio mínimo             
    $sqlUpdMin = "UPDATE cargaPrecioPapas SET precioMinimo = '$valor' WHERE fkZona = $fkZona AND fechaCargaPrecio = CURDATE()";
    
    //Update precio máximo
    $sqlUpdMax = "UPDATE cargaPrecioPapas SET precioMaximo = '$valor' WHERE fkZona = $fkZona AND fechaCargaPrecio = CURDATE()";
    
    $resultadoNull = $conn->query($sqlNull);
    $max = $conn->query($sqlMax);
    $min = $conn->query($sqlMin);
    
    if ($resultadoNull->num_rows > 0) {
        if($valor > $max){
            if (mysqli_query($conn, $sqlUpdMax)) {
                echo "si.";
            } else {
                echo "Error: " . $sqlUpdMax . mysqli_error($conn);
            }
        }else if($valor < $max && $valor > $min){
            echo "no";
        }else{
            if (mysqli_query($conn, $sqlUpdMin)) {
                echo "si.";
            } else {
                echo "Error: " . $sqlUpdMin . mysqli_error($conn);
            }
        }
    }else{
        if (mysqli_query($conn, $sqlInsert)) {
            echo "si.";
        } else {
            echo "Error: " . $sqlInsert . mysqli_error($conn);
        }
    }
 $conn->close();
```

En Android, hago lo siguiente:

```
private void insertUpdate(){
    //validar que no esté vacío
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(precio.getText().toString())) {
        precio.setError("Por favor, ingrese un precio.");
        precio.requestFocus();
        return;
    }
    final int valor = Integer.parseInt(precio.getText().toString().trim());//convertirlo a int
    final int idUsuario = new PreferenciaIdUsuario(CargaPrecios.this).traerValorGuardado();

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "http://flmprogamma.com/insertarvalores.php", new Response.Listener<String>() {//ya explicado
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            if(response.contains("si")){//respuesta del php
                Toast.makeText(CargaPrecios.this,"Registro correcto.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); //toast
                cerrar();//cierra
            }else{
                Log.d("TAG", "onResponse: " + response); //esto muestra el error en la consola con el nombre TAG
                Toast.makeText(CargaPrecios.this,"Ha surgido un error al ingresar el precio. Error: " + response,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();//toast
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) { }
    }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams()  { //mapa de todos los datos a ingresar
            Map<String,String>parms=new HashMap<String, String>();
            parms.put("valor", String.valueOf(valor));
            parms.put("fkZona", String.valueOf(idZona));
            parms.put("fechaCargaPrecio", formatoHoy);
            parms.put("fkUsuario", String.valueOf(idUsuario));
            return parms;
        }
    };
    RequestQueue requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

El problema está en que siempre hace insert, no hace update,¿Alguien me puede decir donde está mi error?

Comment: Cual es el tipo de dato de la columna fkZona de la tabla cargaPrecioPapas ? Esta  Puedes colocar el script de create de la tabla cargaPrecioPapas? Creo que le esta haciendo siempre insert porque la columna fechaCargaPrecio no esta en NULL

Comment: De hecho, ya he podido solucionarlo pero gracias. Adjuntaré mi solución

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pues, lo que he hecho ha sido corregir la consulta de `MySQL`:

```
$sqlNull = "SELECT * FROM cargaPrecioPapas WHERE fkZona = '$fkZona' AND fechaCargaPrecio = CURDATE() IS NOT NULL";
```

Luego, crear dos consultas que traigan los valores MAX/MIN de mi tabla:

```
$sqlMax = "SELECT precioMaximo FROM cargaPrecioPapas WHERE fkZona = '$fkZona' AND fechaCargaPrecio = CURDATE()";
$sqlMin = "SELECT precioMinimo FROM cargaPrecioPapas WHERE fkZona = '$fkZona' AND fechaCargaPrecio = CURDATE()";
```

Creo las consultas:

```
$resultadoNull = $conn->query($sqlNull);
$max = $conn->query($sqlMax);
$min = $conn->query($sqlMin);
```

Y empiezo con los resultados:

```
if ($resultadoNull->num_rows > 0) {
    
    //para traer el valor max y setearlo
    $rowsMax = mysqli_fetch_array($max);
    $valorMax = $rowsMax[0];
    
    //para traer el valor min y setearlo
    $rowsMin = mysqli_fetch_array($min);
    $valorMin = $rowsMin[0];
    
    if($valor > $valorMax){
        if (mysqli_query($conn, $sqlUpdMax)) {
            echo "si.";
        } else {
            echo "Error: " . $sqlUpdMax . mysqli_error($conn);
        }
    }else if($valor < $valorMax && $valor > $valorMin){
        echo "Nada que hacer.";
    }else{
        if (mysqli_query($conn, $sqlUpdMin)) {
            echo "si.";
        } else {
            echo "Error: " . $sqlUpdMin . mysqli_error($conn);
        }
    }
 }else{
    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sqlInsert)) {
        echo "si.";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sqlInsert . mysqli_error($conn);
    }
}
$conn->close();
```